# How do you make a star symbol with the compose key in Linux?

Tags: x11, compose-key

I know how to make a heart with this sequence: `composeKey`, `<`, `3`

But how do you make a star ★?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at your `.XCompose` file in your home directory.  You probably have a line like:

```
<Multi_key> <asterisk> <asterisk>        :"★" U2605 # BLACK STAR
```

If not, add that line, and you should be good to go with `<Compose> * *`

Comment: If you create `~/.XCompose` (it doesn't normally exist), this overrides all existing compose sequences. You need to copy the standard ones from `/usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose` (the location may vary on some distributions).

Comment: It's been so long since I first did that and pushed my dotfiles to a repository that I forgot that detail.  Good catch!

Comment: Sweet. No Linux at the moment, so I'll try when I get a chance. Thanks!

Comment: @trusktr no need to copy the file, just add the line `include "%L"` in the very beginning of your `~/.XCompose` file *(that works, I did it ;)*. You may also look at [man 5 compose](http://linux.die.net/man/5/compose) for more info.